# Form returning null after coming back to the initial user control

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to Windows forms and having an issue handling all the user controls. I have 3 User Controls, and when I click a accept button it takes me to the second screen (which is user control 2) but then when I click cancel on the second screen it brings me back to the first screen (I load the first user control again) the issue now is that when I click again "Accept" the welcome user control returns null and errors.

private void Viewer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            formPanel.Controls.Clear();
            formPanel.Controls.Add(wel);
        }

```
    private void SwapControls(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (formPanel.Controls.Contains(wel))
        {
            formPanel.Controls.Remove(wel);
            formPanel.Controls.Add(p);
        }
        else if (formPanel.Controls.Contains(pin) && IsAuthenticated)
        {
            formPanel.Controls.Remove(p);
            formPanel.Controls.Add(m);
        }
        else if(formPanel.Controls.Contains(pin) && !Global.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            formPanel.Controls.Remove(p);
            formPanel.Controls.Add(wel);
        }
```

So the first time around it loads up the welcome user control, then there I click "Accept" and it clears the User control and loads up the second one "Enter Pin Control", from there when I click "Cancel" I remove that User Control and Load up again Welcome. BUT now, when I click Accept, I get a null in this line in the welcome user control

```
 this.AddControl(this, new EventArgs());
```

Again, I am new to windows forms and I am learning, any inputs would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are reusing your `UserControls` don't remove the handlers when you remove them from the `Form`, just make sure you remove them when you are finished using your `UserControls`.

Try something like this.

```
private void SwapControls(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (formPanel.Controls.Contains(wel)) 
    { 
        formPanel.Controls.Remove(wel); 
        formPanel.Controls.Add(pin); 
    } 
    else if (formPanel.Controls.Contains(pin) && Global.Instance.IsAuthenticated) 
    { 
        formPanel.Controls.Remove(pin); 
        formPanel.Controls.Add(mmenu); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        formPanel.Controls.Remove(pin); 
        formPanel.Controls.Add(wel); 
    } 
}
```

---

```
/// <summary>
/// Clean up any resources being used.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    wel.AddControl -= new EventHandler(SwapControls);
    pin.AddControl -= new EventHandler(SwapControls);
    pin.ReturnWelcome -= new EventHandler(SwapControls); 

    if (disposing && (components != null))
    {
        components.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked, the only thing i dont understand is when i need to remove the handlers... can I just leave them there?.

Comment: If your UserControls are always instantiated I would just remove them in the Dispose Method of your `Form`

Comment: I am sorry, how would i remove a user control? in the dispose section?

Comment: See this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx). I was talking about the Handlers not the Controls.